# evitar log de erro com conexão mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Galera eu faço uma conexão com o mysql usando o php. Faço dessa forma:

```
mysqli_connect($ip_bd_mysql, $login_bd_mysql, $senha_bd_mysql, $banco);
```

O problema e que tem hora que o nome do BANCO esta errado, e o sistema me retorna um erro. Como faço para oculta esse erro e personalizar ele. para informar que ouve um erro com os dados da conexão.

Comment: Você exibe os erros em ambiente de produção? um if na conexão já resolve.

Comment: em ambiente de produção não. Mas ele fica gerando um log com o erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um `trycatch` para qualquer exceção que ocorra ele caias numa área onde você pode personalizar a resposta:

```
try {
    mysqli_connect($ip_bd_mysql, $login_bd_mysql, $senha_bd_mysql, $banco);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    return "Minha mensagem...";
}
```

Você pode ainda forçar erros, e ele irá cair neste mesmo `catch`, por exemplo:

```
try {
    if($ip_bd_mysql == '127.0.0.1')
          throw new Exception("Minha mensagem de erro customizada");
    mysqli_connect($ip_bd_mysql, $login_bd_mysql, $senha_bd_mysql, $banco);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    return $e->getMessage();
}
```

Na variável `$e`, você ainda possui métodos para ter informações relevantes do erro, como a mensagem de erro original, arquivo e linha que ocorreram o erro entre outras...

Para ver exatamente basta dar um `var_dump(get_class_methods($e));`.

Para desabilitar `warning` e `notice` tente colocar o seguinte trecho antes da execução:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Comment: tentei dessa forma e o erro continua

Comment: Qual erro no log exatamente ele está gerando, neste caso ele vai pegar apenas `FATAL_ERROR`, se for um `NOTICE` ou `WARNING`, ai você vai precisar desabilitar na produção para que não grave esses logs...

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia!

Se você deseja ignorar apenas o erro dessa função, tente utilizar o @ junto:

```
@mysqli_connect($ip_bd_mysql, $login_bd_mysql, $senha_bd_mysql, $banco);
```

Abs